# What does double dash do?

Tags: linux, bash, email

I know that this script will send into email and has a subject,recipient and from. My question is can anyone give me a good explanation of what is the use of "-- -f" in this script?

```
echo "Hello World" > output.tmp

SUBJECT="SEND"
EMAIL=mymail@example.com
mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" -- -f frommail@example.com <output.tmp
```

Comment: Type `man 1 mail` in your terminal.

Comment: Yes sir I read it. but there is no "--" and -f is Read in the contents of your mbox (or the specified file) for processing; when you quit, mail writes undeleted messages back to this file.

Comment: Your documentation might be different, but nine says this in the first line of the synopsis: `mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to addr... [-- sendmail-options...]`

Comment: sorry sir i cant understand. can you explain it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the `-f` option to Sendmail sets the envelope sender (if your Sendmail is configured to allow this override).

Understanding the difference between envelope and headers requires some understanding of SMTP, but the twenty-word summary is you can control what ends up in `Return-Path:` and thus e.g. where bounces will be sent.

`mail` invokes Sendmail internally, and is written to understand the special option `--` as a mark to stop parsing the remaining options and just pass them on to Sendmail verbatim.  This is not a universal convention, but a fairly common arrangement for wrappers which do something simple and then pass over control to a complex back-end tool.

Comment: Thank You sir for the good explanation so "--" means passing to?

Comment: Not generally.  See updated answer.

Comment: Nice! BIG THANKS to you sir!

Comment: @DontStopLearning In general `--` marks the end of command line arguments to a program. Everything after `--` should not be regarded as an argument to the program. This makes it possible to remove files that are named like opitons. For instance removing a file called `-f` is `rm -- -f`.

Comment: awesome sir! I tried "touch -f" its error then I tried "touch -- -f" then theres a file now "-f" thanks now its clear to me. Thanks sir!